# PHP Function Executes when not called

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Something very bizarre is occurring in my simple script. I have a static function that is passed $_GET data from the server and runs a prepared statement on it.

the odd part is that this function is called inside and if statement and when the if is not met the SQL prepared statement will still run but nothing else in the function will.

```
if(Filter::isBlacklisted($domain) || $domain == null || Filter::forbiddenCountry($country)) {

    $pid = ($_GET['pid'] == null) ? 0 : $_GET['pid'];
    $tid = ($_GET['tid'] == null) ? 0 : $_GET['tid'];

    //THIS WILL NOT ECHO OUT CAUSE THE IF IS NOT MET
    echo "here";

    //IF I UNCOMMENT THIS THE QUERY WILL NOT RUN
    //exit; 

    //THIS LINE IS THE CULPRIT, ITS QUERY RUNS ON EVERY PAGE REQUESTS
    Filter::blockedRequest($tid,$pid); 

}
else {

    echo "there";

    exit;

}
```

here is the corresponding static function

```
 public static function blockedRequest($tid,$pid) {

    //The QUERY executes but this will not echo out
    echo "Hello";


    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $mysqli = DB::dbConnect();

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO adserver.requests VALUES(?,1,1,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE requests=requests+1, blocked=blocked+1")) {

      $stmt->bind_param("isi",$tid,$date,$pid);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
      $mysqli->close();

    }

    return;

  }
```

Each request being sent does not meet the first if statement and goes to the else statement which echoes out "there". So the If statement works as it should, but the sql statement still executes but the echo in the static function does not run only the sql prepared statement.

The server does not run memcache,opcache or any other caching solution so it's not that.

Also the query is not called anywhere else in the code just here. the containing class does not make any calls to the static function through any other functions.

I am baffled, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: doesn't change anything, but makes the code look cleaner.

Comment: Well... still uunclear for me. What is the specific issue? What is the expected output?

Comment: Are you sure that this is all of your code, it seems impossible the `if` condition to execute the static function?

Comment: instead of `echo "Hello";` inside of `blockedRequest`, put an `exit()`. If the query still runs you can be 100% confident you are looking in the wrong part of your code.

Comment: `echo in the static function does not run` If the echo does not run then the function does not run too. Search some where else.

Comment: That is all the code. It ONLY executes the query, and not the "here" echo. So the If statement does not actually run. BUT if I comment out the static function inside the if statement then magically the query doesn't run anymore. So it is only this piece of the code that is causing the query to run

Comment: @Scott changed out the echo to exit and the query stopped running so i am looking at the right part of the code, but no closer to any reason why

Comment: @wmfrancia, The next step would be to move the `exit` to `echo "here"` and check the results (make sure to delete the `exit` inside of `blockedRequest`). If its still not running, then your `if` statement *is* running and therefore incorrect.

Comment: Hook up a live debugger (yes, this can be a bit daunting if you haven't done this before) and step through your code execution line by line.

Comment: Maybe your sending multiple requests and the second is hiding the echo from the first. if you are on a typical LAMP stack run `tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log` while you refresh the page.

Comment: Also try adding `|| False` to the if statement to be certain its never entered

Comment: @dan08 Bingo! I am running NGINX but it was the same issue. The browser is sending a favicon.ico request with the normal request and the first executes the query while the second overwrites the previous echo. Since you got the right answer I would love to accept it if you can add it below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are sending multiple requests without realizing it. If the first request entered the if statement and the second one did not, it would overwrite the first echo and produce the result you are seeing.

To check what requests are being sent to the server, watch your access logs while you reproduce the behavior (refresh the page or submit the form).

Typical LAMP: `tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log`

nginx: `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log`